# Extracting HTML tables and store them in separate file

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote a code to extract subparts of tables, but I want to extract every  tag from the input, and then store them in a separate html file

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(myInput)
table = soup.find('table', {'class': '*'})
```

I expect the code to show me all tables containted on the input text, but it outputs an error code because the * is not defined

EDIT : * means every table in the file, like saying *.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`class` is the attribute that you are searching for, but you have to tell `soup` which class you are using to get table

```
<table class='HiClass'>
A
</table>
<table class='MiClass'>
B
</table>
<table class='*'>
C
</table>
```

For instance,

```
table1 = soup.find('table', {'class': '*'})
table2 = soup.find('table', {'class': 'HiClass'})
```

You'll get "C" table in `table1` and "A" in `table2`.

To get ***all*** tables, just use

```
table = soup.findAll('table')
```

and you will get all elements which use `<table>` tag or tags try returned as a list

Demo:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_request(url):      
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html5lib') 
    table = soup.findAll('table')
    return table

url ='https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp'
print(get_request(url))
```

Comment: What we can do if file contain 5 tables with no class ?

Comment: add the code that i provided bro. ill enter full demo in my edit

Comment: class is not essential to define. it use to filter. if you need all tabels. then you dont haft to filter.